# .tex files not found when placed in a folder declared in TEXINPUTS

Tags: variables, latex

I have a set of documents based on a LaTeX template. Every document has its own folder, as following:

```
docs-folder
 |-doc #1
 |-doc #2
 ...
 |-doc #n
 |-texmf
   |-tex
   |-bibtex
   |-fonts
   |-docs
   |-misc
     |-logo.jpg
     |-acronyms.tex
```

I wrote the template on my own, and, for every document (from #1 to #n) it loads the files `logo.jpg` and `acronyms.tex` with `\includegraphics{logo.jpg}` and `\input{acronyms.tex}`.

The path ..\docs-folder\texmf is set as a project root in MikTeX, and the local texmf tree is recognized properly, excluding the `misc` folder.

So, the path `..\docs-folder\texmf\misc` is set as the value of the TEXINPUTS environment variable (under Windows). This is done in order to avoid an unwanted replication of the two files.

What happens is that, when I compile one of the documents, the file `acronyms.tex` is not found, while the `logo.jpg` is correctly found by PDFLaTeX.

I have no wonder why the acronyms.tex file is not loaded.

Comment: What does "kpsewhich acronyms.tex" say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On unix systems the solution is to run `texhash` or `mktexlsr`. According to [this page](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=2551), the equivalent solution for MikTeX is to run MikTeX settings and click the "Refresh FNDB" button.